# Redirecting print() output in compiled Nashorn function

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I'm trying to capture the `print()` output from a compiled JavaScript function using Nashorn. This works as expected when using the `ScriptEngine` without a dedicated `ScriptContext`:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager()
        .getEngineByName("nashorn");

// Create a StringWriter for print() output
StringWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();
engine.getContext().setWriter(myWriter);

// Compile the functino in the context.
String code = "function testPrint() {print('Hello World');}";
engine.eval(code);
ScriptObjectMirror fn = (ScriptObjectMirror) engine.getContext()
        .getAttribute("testPrint");

// Call the function and test the output.
fn.call("testPrint");
System.out.println("StringWriter contents: " + myWriter);
```

Output:

```
StringWriter contents: Hello World
```

However, if I do it in an isolated `ScriptContext`, the `print()` output *always* goes to `System.out`.

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager()
        .getEngineByName("nashorn");

// Set up an isolated context.
Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
ScriptContext isolatedContext = new SimpleScriptContext();
isolatedContext.setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

// Create a StringWriter for print() output
StringWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();
isolatedContext.setWriter(myWriter);

// Compile the functino in the context.
String code = "function testPrint() {print('Hello World');}";
engine.eval(code, isolatedContext);
ScriptObjectMirror fn = (ScriptObjectMirror) isolatedContext
        .getAttribute("testPrint");

// Call the function and test the output.
fn.call("testPrint");
System.out.println("StringWriter contents: " + myWriter);
```

This produces:

```
Hello World
StringWriter contents:
```

The first line is printed to System.out when the function is invoked; the second is the result of the last line of the code, showing the StringWriter to be empty.

How do I get a function compiled in a manually-built context to behave like one compiled with the engine's default context?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `set` methods of  `SimpleScriptContext`, before using .

```
public SimpleScriptContext() {
        engineScope = new SimpleBindings();
        globalScope = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        writer = new PrintWriter(System.out , true);
        errorWriter = new PrintWriter(System.err, true);
    }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
    public void setReader(Reader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    public void setWriter(Writer writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
    }


    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    public void setErrorWriter(Writer writer) {
        this.errorWriter = writer;
    }
```